# javascript tabular function how to add active class to active button

Tags: jquery, css

This is my javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var showcont = [];
    var showcont_containers = [];

    $('#tabs ul li a').each(function () {  

    // note that this only compares the pathname, not the entire url

    // which actually may be required for a more terse solution.   

     if (this.pathname == window.location.pathname) {
            showcont.push(this);
            showcont_containers.push($(this.hash).get(0));
        };

    });

    $(showcont).click(function(e){  
     $(showcont_containers).hide().filter(this.hash).fadeIn();   
       e.preventDefault();
    });
    </script>
```

How to add active class to `#tabs ul li a`? Please help me

Comment: This is not a javascript at all tag your questions properly

Comment: This is working code..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add or remove class, you can use `$(this).addClass('active')` or `$(this).removeClass('active')`. Assuming the `if` statement is working in the code as intented, following code should work.

```
if (this.pathname == window.location.pathname) {
   showcont.push(this);
   showcont_containers.push($(this.hash).get(0));
   this.addClass('active');
};
```

With the following code you can add "active" class to the `<a>` element you click, and remove it from the siblings.

```
$('#tabs ul li a').on('click', function()
{
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

This however won't work if you are refreshing page after every `<a>` element click.

Comment: not working properly. could you please add any class to existing functions instead of taking new functions?

Comment: Edited the answer, added the if statement code. Check if that works as intended.